# Install Territories 1.0 in my Developer Org

Tags: territory-management, developer-org

With Territories 2.0 out, when I enable Territories in my Dev org it automatically uses 2.0.  Is there any way I can enable Territories 1.0 in my Dev org?  I'm trying to do some work for some clients who have the older version but I cannot do the development in their Sandboxes and so must use a .dev org.

Comment: I do not think this is something you could do without contacting SF support....

Comment: @Eric And they are usually less than helpful when using a Dev org...

Comment: You are being too nice with your assessment :)

Comment: I had to contact SFDC Support. They created a ticket and moved us back to TM1.0

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be to contact Salesforce support and to ask them to enable Territories 1.0... though I would encourage you to use v2, as v1 is EOL.